# How can I change the context value in Watson Assistant

Tags: arrays, json, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have problems to change a value, I have this context at the beginning of the conversation

```
    "context": {
        "Trips" : {
            "Germany": {
                "Info": null,
                "Dates": null,
                "Prices": null,
                "Flights": null,
                "Layaway": null,
                "Requirements": null
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I change the value of Information to True when a user requests information

I try to use an array like this

```
    "context": {
        "Trips" : {
            "Germany": [
                {
                    "Info": null
                },
                {
                    "Dates": null
                },
                {
                    "Prices": null
                },
                {
                    "Flights": null
                },
                {
                    "Layaway": null
                },
                {
                    "Requirements": null
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

And I use "**Then set context**" to change the value using this

```
"context": {
    "remove": "\"<? $Trips.Germany.removeValue({\"Info\"==null\") ?>\"",
    "experiences": "<? $Trips.Germany.append({Info : True}) ?>"
}
```

But I think this is not the best way to do it. I want to do this without using an array if it is not possible. I have another question.

How to access to the value when I use "**If assistant recognizes**"?

I have

```
$Trips.Germany.indexOf("Info")==true
```

But I get the error:

SpelEvaluationException when evaluating dialog node ID [response_1_1576705519309]. The syntax of condition [$Trips.Germany.indexOf("Info")==true] is valid, but cannot be evaluated. Check that objects in expression are not null or out of bounds. SpEL evaluation error: EL1008E: Property or field 'Germany' cannot be found on object of type 'JsonArray' - maybe not public? (and there is 1 more error in the log)

Is there a way that only one value is recognized without relying on others?

Comment: It would be better if you embed the code samples instead of just linking :)

Comment: I´m sorry, it's my first post on Stackoverflow